# Could not open input file: /path/artisan using supervisor

Tags: php, laravel, docker, supervisord

Ciao,
I am trying to use a supervisor to run the Laravel job in the background but it seems like, I won't go far without your assistance, when the supervisor starts, in my worker.log i found that it couldn't open artisan file, so i tried all online solution for issues related to mine but nothing works!
my app is running well and even i try to run php artisan queue:work in my container it works like charm so, i don't know what's the issue is!

[image: In my terminal]

Any help would be appreciated, also if you think there is another way to do so please let me know!! if also, you find that my code needs to be updated for better performance please let me also!
Happy coding!

Comment: If you run your containers, and log into your supervisor container, can you manually execute the command there?

Comment: @Techno, yes, but it is showing that error! "Could not open input file: /app/artisan"

Comment: So if you check the directory(from logged in user perspective), is the file there? And what are the file permissions?

Comment: It seems like I am not in that directory! I think the issue is in the above files, but I can't figure out where!

Comment: "It seems like I am not in that directory! " >> That was exactly what I was looking for. It really helps to break down the issue by logging into the container manually and checking directories. I had a similar problem, where my dockerfile copied files into the container, then ran composer to create vendor folder. But there never was a vendor folder. My issue was that my volume overrides the files by the version without the vendor folder. I would suggest trying to remove the volume definition in the supervisor service and see if it works. At least we might be able to pinpoint the issue

Comment: I actually that what I was doing seems like it is now accessing it, but it's now running this line of code.
 
`CMD php artisan key:generate && php artisan optimize:clear && php artisan migrate && composer dumpautoload && php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8180` 

Instead of running `PHP artisan queue:work` from the supervisor

Comment: Ahh yes, you can only have 1 entrypoint per container. It's a bit of a pain( I had the same problem adding logic to a php image, it would either run my logic OR run php). You can bypass this by using something like `ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]` and then put both the `serve` command and the supervisor logic into the bash file. It's a bit tricky to get to work, but sources like this helped me alot: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/

Comment: Ohh really? let me go through this, I will keep you posted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [techno](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2595985/techno), the issue was solved successfully; also, if found this docker image [redditsaved/laravel-supervisord](https://hub.docker.com/r/redditsaved/laravel-supervisord), it is easy to configure; just take a look if you are facing supervisord issues to use a supervisor in dockerized Laravel application!